# css - how to align the flex centre item?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, tailwind-css

I have a React Component.
[image]

If the lengths of the labels(Football etc) are different, the starting position of the progress bar is different. I want to make them always start at the same position. Is it possible to do so using `flex`?

MyComponent.tsx

```
import React from "react";

const INITIAL_CATEGORIES = [
  { id: 1, label: "Football" },
  { id: 2, label: "Basketball & Baseball" },
];

const CategoryItem = ({ label }) => {
  return (
    <div className="flex justify-between items-center">
      <span>{label}</span>
      <div className="w-6/12 bg-indigo-100 rounded-full h-2.5 dark:bg-gray-700">
        <div
          className="bg-blue-600 h-2.5 rounded-full"
          style={{ width: "65%" }}
        >
          123
        </div>
      </div>
      <span>$650.00 / $ 1,000.00</span>
    </div>
  );
};

export default function Dictator() {
  return (
    <div className="px-5 py-5 bg-white rounded">
      <div className="flex flex-col gap-3 mt-4">
        {INITIAL_CATEGORIES.map(({ id, label }) => (
          <CategoryItem key={id} label={label} />
        ))}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: are you using Tailwind CSS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `flex-n` to arrange the elements in `CategoryItem` component instead of `justify-between`.

So I adjusted your `CategoryItem` component.

```
const CategoryItem = ({ label }) => {
  return (
    <div className="flex items-center">
      <span className="flex-1">{label}</span>
      <div className="flex-2 w-6/12 bg-indigo-100 rounded-full h-2.5 dark:bg-gray-700">
        <div
          className="bg-blue-600 h-2.5 rounded-full"
          style={{ width: "65%" }}
        >
          123
        </div>
      </div>
      <span className="flex-1 text-right">$650.00 / $ 1,000.00</span>
    </div>
  );
};
```

You can check in this [tailwind playground](https://play.tailwindcss.com/WqwVlN0WM5).

Answer (score 0):

Grids are better suited for your scenario. You can learn a lot more about grids here  [CSS Tricks guide to Grids](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/).

```
const CategoryItem = ({ label }) => {
  return (
    <div className="grid grid-cols-2 justify-between place-items-center">  {/* Changes here */}
      <span>{label}</span>
      <div className="w-6/12 bg-indigo-100 rounded-full h-2.5 dark:bg-gray-700">
        <div
          className="bg-blue-600 h-2.5 rounded-full"
          style={{ width: "65%" }}
        >
          123
        </div>
      </div>
      <span>$650.00 / $ 1,000.00</span>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Or, if you want to achieve the same with flexbox, you can set the label to grow and it will take the maximum space available to it, as the progress bar will be same for all the categoies.

```
const CategoryItem = ({ label }) => {
  return (
    <div className="flex justify-between items-center">
      <span className="flex-grow-1">{label}</span>
      <div className="w-6/12 bg-indigo-100 rounded-full h-2.5 dark:bg-gray-700">
        <div
          className="bg-blue-600 h-2.5 rounded-full"
          style={{ width: "65%" }}
        >
          123
        </div>
      </div>
      <span>$650.00 / $ 1,000.00</span>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Answer (score -2):

To ensure that the progress bars start at the same position regardless of the length of the labels, you can achieve this by setting a **fixed width** for the label column and using `flex-grow for the progress bar column.` This will ensure that the progress bars occupy the remaining space equally. Here's how you can modify your `CategoryItem` component:

```
const CategoryItem = ({ label }) => {
  return (
    <div className="flex justify-between items-center">
      <span className="w-24">{label}</span> {/* Fixed width for the label */}
      <div className="flex-grow bg-indigo-100 rounded-full h-2.5 dark:bg-gray-700">
        <div
          className="bg-blue-600 h-2.5 rounded-full"
          style={{ width: "65%" }}
        >
          123
        </div>
      </div>
      <span>$650.00 / $ 1,000.00</span>
    </div>
  );
};
```

In this modification, I've set a fixed width of `w-24` (adjust this width according to your needs) for the label column, and I've replaced `w-6/12` with `flex-grow` for the progress bar column. This ensures that the progress bar column takes up the remaining space after accommodating the fixed-width label column. Now, regardless of the length of the labels, the progress bars will always start at the same position.

Answer (score -3):

You can try something like

```html
<div style="display: flex; justify-content: center; align-items: center; height: 300px; width: 100%;">
  <div>
    <h1>center-item</h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

This will center the items, as you needed!